# What is the complexity of randomly selecting a non-null element from an array that has nulls?

Tags: arrays, random, time-complexity, big-o

Say I have an array where I want to randomly select elements from the array, but some of the array elements are null, like this:

```
[0, 1, 3, null, 3, 2, null, 9, 12]
```

If I select them at random (with a good, unbiased random number generator), and land on a null, then I select again at random until I find a non-null element. I do it this way to avoid introducing bias into my selections.

The question is: what is the time complexity (in big-O notation, or a more appropriate notation of time-complexity) of such a selection?

Clearly, if all the elements are null, then it will never complete, and if none of the elements are null, then it's O(1), but it's unclear to me how to express the values in between.

*I'm aware that a different way of organizing the array would avoid holes, and then it could always be O(1): I'm not asking how to implement it better, I'm asking how to express this kind of complexity.*

Comment: Not really what you are asking for, but wanted to point out that you don't even need to change the organization of the array, to make the time complexity O(N) (at a cost of O(N) space). Just randomly select in between known nulls instead. IE: Start with randomly choosing between index 0 and 8. If you get index 6, then randomly select between 0 to 5 and 7 to 8. Picking one of the larger of the available intervals is probably better. A random choice between 0 and 5 might lead to index 3. The available intervals are then 0 to 2, 4 to 5, and 7 to 8, any of which will produce valid values.

Comment: I can see how that would work, but wouldn't that add bias into the random selection?  The regions aren't all the same size, after all...

Comment: Fair enough, it would add some bias to the random selection. If that's a major concern you could treat them as linked lists. Where you could have the intervals 0 to 2, 4 to 5 and 7 to 8 counted as a list of 7 elements then randomly select an index from there. Although, you'd then need to determine which interval has the element the index refers to and that seems like it would require using an interval tree, making the algorithm O(N log N). I'm also thinking the average times are O(k/N) for my first algorithm and O((k/N) log k) for this one, where k is the number of nulls.

Comment: The original algorithm in the worst case can be better described via the probability of finding a null value after m iterations, which is O((k/N)^m)), where again k is the number of null values in the array. If the array has no non-null elements, then the probability of a null value being found after an infinite number of iterations is 1 and thus the algorithm does not terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, in the worst case this algorithm never terminates and therefore [`T(n)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is undefined (or infinity).

You may be more interested in [average-case time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity), which is used more often than worst-case complexity to describe [randomized algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm#Computational_complexity) such as yours.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I hadn't considered the possibility that the time complexity might be undefined for this algorithm.